# Current Sidekiq job lost when deploying to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq

I have a Sidekiq job that runs for a while and when I deploy to Heroku and the job is running, it can't finish within in the few seconds.

That is fine, as the job is designed to be able to be re-run if needed.

The problem is that the job gets lost (instead of put back to redis and run again after deploy).

I found that it is advised to set `:timeout: 8` on heroku and I tried it, but it had no effect (also tried seeting to 5).

When there is an exception, I get errors reported, but I don't see any. So not sure what could be wrong.

Any tips on how to debug this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The free version of Sidekiq will push unfinished jobs back to Redis after the timeout has passed, default of 8 seconds.  Heroku gives a process 10 seconds to shut down.  That means we have 2 seconds to get those jobs back to Redis **or they will be lost**.  If your network is slow, if the Redis server is swapping, etc, that 2 sec deadline might not be met and the jobs lost.

You were on the right track: one answer is to lower the timeout so you have a better chance of meeting that deadline.  But network or swapping delay can't be predicted: even 5 seconds might not be enough time.

Under normal healthy conditions, things should work as designed.  Keep your machines healthy (uncongested network, plenty of RAM) and the basic fetch should work well.  Sidekiq Pro's reliable fetch feature is a fundamental redesign of how Sidekiq fetches jobs and works around all of these issues by keeping jobs in Redis all the time so they can't be lost.  But it comes with serious trade offs too: it's more complicated, slower and more Redis intensive than "basic" fetch.

In short, I don't know why you are losing jobs but make sure your instances and Redis server are healthy and the latency is low.

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Using-Redis#life-in-the-cloud

Comment: Reducing the timeout further down to 2s fixed the issue and thats good enough for now. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is actually *feature* of sidekiq - designed to steer you toward paying pro version:
http://sidekiq.org/products/pro

> RELIABILITY
>
> More reliable message processing.
>
> Cloud environments are noisy and unreliable. Seeing timeouts? Wild swings in latency or performance? Ruby VM crashes or processes disappearing?
>
> If a Sidekiq process crashes while processing a job, that job is lost.
>
> If the Sidekiq client gets a networking error while pushing a job to Redis, an exception is raised and the job is not delivered.
>
> Sidekiq Pro uses Redis's RPOPLPUSH command to ensure that jobs will not be lost if the process crashes or gets a KILL signal.
>
> The Sidekiq Pro client can withstand transient Redis outages or timeouts. It will enqueue jobs locally upon error and attempt to deliver those jobs once connectivity is restored.

Deploy terminates all processes that belongs to user, therefore job is lost. There is actually not much you can do there.

Comment: Thanks, is there a way to tell the threads to raise when there are about to be terminated? That would put them back to the queue.

Comment: You can try traping signals: http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Signal.html but I've never done it in this context, so I'm not sure it will be reliable.

Comment: You are implying that the free version loses jobs so you pay for the Pro version.  100% wrong. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/blob/master/lib/sidekiq/manager.rb#L120

Answer (score 3):

As @mike-perham and @esse noted, Sidekiq is designed the way it can loose jobs due to its fetching mechanism. Your options to get around this are:

1. To buy Sidekiq Pro (although it was [reported](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/2531) to cause the same issue)
2. To write your own fetcher (but that would mean you can not use most of 3rd party libraries, as they will not work with your custom fetcher)
3. To mimic Sidekiq Pro's reliable fetch by backing up your jobs data. In case you are up for this way, check out [attentive_sidekiq](https://github.com/twonegatives/attentive_sidekiq) gem which does exactly that.